# Ошибка "object reference not set to an instance of an object" в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

```
private Light myLight;

void Star() {
    myLight = GetComponent <Light> ();
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
        myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
    }
}
```

Хотел сделать чтоб при нажатии на пробел включался/выключался свет, но выдает ошибку

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Нет компонента Light на обьекте

Comment: Как добавить его?

Comment: Add component в окне редактора, нет?

Comment: Он там и так есть

Comment: ох е, у тебя в функция Star вместо Start, не отрабатывает

Comment: боже...Стыдно,исправил, но всё равно не пашет

Comment: ошибка исчезла, но не работает

Comment: Попробуй GetKeyDown и другую клавишу

Comment: Всё равно никак

Comment: Ну не знаю, лично у меня работает если Star на Start исправить

Comment: `ошибка исчезла, но не работает` - что именно не работает? Отладку пытался использовать?)

Answer (score 1):

Метод Star должен называться Start

Работающий код будет вот таким:

```
private Light myLight;

void Start() {
    myLight = GetComponent <Light> ();
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
        myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
    }
}
```

Так же, для того, что бы в методе Start() логика отработала правильно, компонент Light должел быть приатачен к GameObjectу, на котором есть компонент с указанным выше кодом.